# PIL Image for Tkinter doesn't render unless PhotoImage variable is global

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am having trouble converting my PIL image into a Tkinter image, here is my class:

```
class GameText():
    def __init__(self, parent, xPos, yPos, text, tag="default"):
        global drawTex
        self.parent = parent
        self.xPos = xPos
        self.yPos = yPos
        self.text = str(text)
        self.tag = tag

        image = Image.new("RGBA", (400, 400), None)

        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
        draw.text((0, 0), self.text, font=font, fill="white")
        del draw

        drawTex = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
        self.image = self.parent.create_image(self.xPos, self.yPos, image=drawTex, tag=self.tag)
```

No image is displayed at all if drawTex isn't global, and even when it is, only one image is displayed, if I were to create these two objects, only the last would appear.

```
self.test1 = GameText(self, 300, 300, "ab")
self.test2 = GameText(self, 300, 300, "hi")
```

Why does drawTex have to be global and why does only the last image get displayed?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why does drawTex have to be global and why does only the last image get displayed? (Also edited it in)

Comment: because without it, `drawTex` is a local variable that gets garbage-collected when the method returns.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I didn't realise the variable well still required after the image was created, not too sure why the question is getting downvoted though :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just resolved it myself, I have no idea why but adding `self.` to `drawTex` makes it work as intended.

Comment: adding `self` to `drawTex` has the same (generally) effect as globalising `drawTex`.

Comment: ...because prepending `self.` to the `drawTex` variable saved the `PhotoImage` instance created as an attribute of the `GameText` object rather than in a local variable -- so it's no longer deleted as soon as the `__init__()` method returns.